# Derivative of $y= (1-x^{-1})^{-1}$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the derivative of $y= (1-x^{-1})^{-1}$ to make it simple I use the chain rule and

$$u = 1-x^{-1}$$

$$y = u^{-1}$$

$$y' = -1u^{-2}u' = -1(1-x^{-1})^{-2}(x^{-2})$$

The problem is that this is not what my book gets and I am wondering if there is some strange power rule I overlooked or some other way to do this problem that gives me a different answer, or maybe I just need to factor is out somehow.

Comment: I do not see the difference.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the question.

Comment: Jordan, when you subsituted 'back' for $u^{-2}$, you forgot the $\;^{-2}$ part.

Comment: I have that on my paper, I just typed it up wrong.

Comment: Then multiply above and below by $x^2$.

Comment: Most likely, another case where the book gives a simplified answer:  $$-1(1+x^{-1})^{-2}x^{-2}= {-1\over (1-{1\over x})^2}\cdot {1\over x^2} = {-1\over x^2\cdot(1-{1\over x})^2}  =  {-1\over \bigl( x(1-{1\over x})\bigr)^2}  =  {-1\over  (x-1 )^2} .$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y = \left( 1 - x^{-1} \right)^{-1} = \frac1{1 - \frac1x} = \frac{x}{x-1} = 1 + \frac1{x-1}$$
Hence, $$y' = - \frac1{(x-1)^2}$$

To proceed through you method of using chain rule, setting $u = (1-x^{-1})$, we have that $y = u^{-1}$. Hence, $$y' = -\frac{u'}{u^2}.$$ Note that $$u' = \frac1{x^2}.$$
Hence, we get that $$y' = - \frac{1/x^2}{(1-x^{-1})^2} = - \frac{1/x^2}{(1-1/x)^2} = - \frac{1/x^2}{(x-1)^2/x^2} = - \frac1{(x-1)^2}$$

The error you made was that you did not write $u^{-2}$ correctly. $\displaystyle u^{-2} = \frac1{(1-x^{-1})^2}$

Comment: I see how that is correct, but I do not see why my way of doing it is incorrect. It seems to follow all the rules.

Comment: I do not follow the second to last part where the x^2 dissapears.

Comment: @Jordan $$(1-x^{-1})^2 = (1-1/x)^2 = (x-1)^2/x^2.$$ Hence, $$\frac{1/x^2}{(x-1)^2/x^2} = \frac1{(x-1)^2}.$$